# Why do we have "Coulombic" but not "Coulombian"?

Tags: mathematics, science

In physics, we have *Coulombic* interaction. Why do we have "Coulombic" but not "Coulombian"? At first, I think that because the letter ***b*** from *Coulomb* decides which suffix comes after it, but when I look at the *Jacobian* word in mathematics, I think that this hypothesis is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because in vocabulary, nothing succeeds like success. We do in fact have *Coulombian*, and it's older and still in use.

Still, the OED definition for it is simply:

> = coulombic adj.

While it was around since 1835 (they list it as 1836, but it's an 1836 publication of a work clearly written in 1835), it didn't see much use. When someone in the early 20th century (the first citation the OED has for it is 1936) decided an adjective would work better than a modifying noun in "Coulomb field" and either not knowing *Coulombian*, or misremembering it, they used *Coulombic* in "Coulombic field" and it caught on.

[image]

That said, while *Coulombic* took over, adjective use of *Coulomb* is much greater in at least that context (lower-case *coulombian* had no results):

[image]